# Using prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have defined a couple of functions inside my javascript which work perfectly, but when I put it inside a prototype it just doesn't seem to work.

wall.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery-1.4.4.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/CommentManager.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/Reply.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/Comment.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        CommentManager();
        $("form#newMessage").submit(function(){
            var message = $("input#newMessageTxt").val();
            var newComment = new Comment(message);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="message">
        <form id="newMessage"&gt;>
            <input type="text" id="newMessageTxt" height="200px" value="Write a message" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" ></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

but the weird part is when I run the debugging tool in googlechrome, the $("form#newMessage").submit doesn't call at all. So Comment(message) is never created (which is where I have set up the prototype functions)

Comment.js:

```
function Comment(message){
    var self = this;
    var message = message;

    var comment = document.createElement("li");
    comment.id = "comment";
    comment.textContent = message;
    //empty reply field
    var replyField = document.createElement("ul");
    replyField.id = "replyField";
    //create the appropriate buttons
    createButtons(comment);
    //append the replyField
    comment.appendChild(replyField);
    //insert into wall
    addComment(comment);
    //effect after insertion
    Effect(comment);
    $(comment).mouseleave(function() {mouseOut(comment);});
    $(comment).mouseenter(function() {mouseOver(comment);});
    return comment;
}
Comment.prototype={
    deleteComment : function (comment){
        $(comment).fadeOut();
        setTimeout(function() {comment.parentNode.removeChild(comment);},500);
    },
//there are more methods here
}
```

Commentmanager.js:

```
function CommentManager(){
    var owner = null; 

    var wall = document.createElement("ul");
    wall.id = "wall";

    document.body.appendChild(wall);
    return wall;
}

function addComment(comment){
    var wall = document.getElementById("wall");
    wall.appendChild(comment);
}
```

Comment: Sadly, all I could do was retag, since I don't speak jquery. `prototype` was a little misleading.

Comment: Actually, 'prototype' is a descriptive term within javascript which has a different meaning than everywhere else in software development (unfortunately :(  ). see http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html for a description of what 'prototypal' means in js. perhaps `javascript-prototype` should be a tag?

Comment: Using jQuery and you have inline JavaScript on the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Where is `createButtons` defined?  (in Comment.js)?

Also, you you titled that last file as Commentmanager.js, but wall.html has CommentManager.js (notice the capital M in wall.js). I'm assuming that's a typo here in the SO question, but make sure that your filenames on the server match the html script tags.